# How to create a new column in R based on information in a sample table?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'd like to create a new column in my data that contains the age of samples specified in another dataframe. Here's a sample of my data:

```
       Depth Name                                                    X Statistic Total.Cell.Number
1              B1                                                  fcs        NA             95208
2         >    B1                                     fcs/Immune Cells     43.40             41276
3       > >    B1                        fcs/Immune Cells/Single Cells     93.70             38686
4     > > >    B1                   fcs/Immune Cells/Single Cells/Live     96.90             37506
5   > > > >    B1         fcs/Immune Cells/Single Cells/Live/CD45 High      9.10              3413
6 > > > > >    B1 fcs/Immune Cells/Single Cells/Live/CD45 High/B Cells      7.76               265
```

And here's the sample information dataframe:

```
   Sample Age
1      B1   2
2      B2   2
3      B3   2
4      B4   2
5      B5   2
6      B6   2
7      B7  12
8      B8  12
9      B9  12
10    B10  12
11    B11  12
12    B12  12
```

I would like to create a new column in the original dataframe, Age, that matches the Age specified for each sample in the second dataframe. Here's the catch though: because this will be part of a function with an unknown number of samples and different ages/names every time, I cannot hard code this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So in your example you need a column in dataframe1 with column age of group B1. Ergo 2 of all B1?

Comment: Yes, but there are other samples farther down in the dataframe. So some rows have B1, others have B2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::left_join(df1, sampleInfo, by = c("name" = "Sample"))`